# How check my edit text input value is equals to the array value

Tags: android, arrays, android-edittext, android-studio-3.0

I want to check whether my edit text value is equal to the array value
`String[] zipcode = {"123","456"}` toast success if match else failed.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText et_zipcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etzipcode);
        Button bt_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btsave);

        bt_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String[] zipcodes = {"123","456"};
                if (et_zipcode.getText().equals(zipcodes)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I which format do you want to enter the values in your edit text like only 1 zip code or multiple zip codes?

Comment: On you code you are trying to compare a `String` and and `array` and that's not allowed, you have to itterate the `array` and see if any value matches the input of you `editText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it might help you

```
String edittext = et_zipcode.getText();
for(int i = 0; i<zipcodes.size(); i++){
if(edittext .equals(zipcodes.get(i).toString)){
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] zipcodes = {"123","456"};
   boolean contains = Arrays.asList(zipcodes ).contains(et_zipcode.getText());
    if (contains)
    {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    else {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition for checking if edit text contains zip codes:

```
if(Arrays.asList(zip).contains(et_zipcode.getText().toString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean isSuccess = true;
            String[] zipcodes = {"123", "456"};
            for (int i = 0; i < zipcodes.length; i++) {
                if (et_zipcode.getText().toString().equals(zipcodes[i])) {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            if (isSuccess) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 **try this one**

bt_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String[] zipcodes = {"123","456"};
             String entertext = et_zipcode.getText().toString();
                 boolean result=   Arrays.asList(zipcodes).contains(entertext);
                  System.out.println(result);
                    if(result==true ){
                        System.out.println("matched");
                       }else {
                     System.out.println(" not matched"); }

                }
            });
        }
```